# Trigger browser extension to open from background script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

Background: I am developing a browser extension, where I get a certain text of a page via a context menu and save it into the Chrome storage. From there I have another script which gets the text from the storage and pastes it into a textarea.

Now I want to open the browser extension from the background script to make it seem like when you click the context menu, the extension with the certain text already in the textarea opens up.

code of my background script:

```
var contextMenuItem = 
{
    "id": "getFakeText",
    "title": "GetFakeText",
    "contexts": ["selection"]
};
chrome.contextMenus.create(contextMenuItem);

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(clickData){
    if(clickData.menuItemId =="getFakeText" && clickData.selectionText){
        chrome.storage.sync.set({"Text": clickData.selectionText}, function() {});
    }
//here I then want to open the extension

})
```

Pressing this Button in the Tooltip:
[image: Pressing this Button in the Tooltip]

I want to open this:
[image: I want to open this]

Pressing the tooltip Button on Picture 1 should result in opening the Pop Up of the Browser extension (Picture 2).
Don't generate a new Tab or something.

Comment: Not the real popup but you can open a new window by using chrome.windows.create.

Comment: Okay thats not what I meant

Comment: Then send a [message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to the [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) which will add that textarea element in the web page.

Comment: @wOxxOm no this is unfortunately not an option

Comment: Extensions can't open that popup programmatically in stable release of Chrome so my comments above describe the most popular alternatives.